# Installing a React project from GitHub

Tags: reactjs, typescript, github

Good day to all forum users. I need to install a project from GitHub locally, but I'm having some difficulties.
The link is https://github.com/thekevinscott/ml-classifier-ui/tree/master/example.
It's giving me an error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Dev\ml-classifier-ui-master\example\scripts\start.js'
[1]     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
[1]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
[1]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
[1]     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
[1]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
[1]   requireStack: []
```

I performed the following steps:

```
yarn add ml-classifier-ui
```

```
yarn watch.
```

Please, tell me how to run the project locally.